# How to run a single jUnit test on Multiple classes having different names?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit

I have different classes in the resource package having different names. I need to run a single junit test case on each of the class. But I'm stuck on it that how can I run a single junit testsuite on multiple target classes?

Here, I'm creating a single variable for a single class and test case is running on it. But I need to run the same test case on multiple target classes.

```
public class multipleTest {

    private multiple multipleUnderTest;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        multipleUnderTest = new multiple();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGrade() {
        // Setup
        final int total = 300;
        final char expectedResult = 'C';

        // Run the test
        final char result = multipleUnderTest.grade(total);

        // Verify the results
        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the multiple classes result from a single junit Test. But it is testing a single target class. and need another test case to run on another class.

Comment: All you need is another variable, and another method call. It's just Java code. But why would you test multiple different classes inside the same test? How would that make anything better than having separate test classes? And why don't you respect the Java naming conventions, too?

Comment: I'm working on mutation testing, and I need to run all the mutated classes with a single file. It will give me a comparison result that which mutated file is killed or Alive.

Comment: I'm not sure what "running a class" means, but well, do it. What prevents you? `Foo foo = new Foo(); Bar bar = new Bar(); foo.run(); bar.run();`. There, you have executed two methods of two different classes.

Comment: Yeah, I got the idea, Thank you so much.

Comment: have you looked at how pitest solves the problem? https://github.com/hcoles/pitest